# Turning off anti-aliasing: inconsistency between 'info' window and valid python commands

Tags: python, rendering, antialiasing, workbench-render-engine

I want to render an image without anti-aliasing.
Using the UI, I select the *Workbench* engine.
Then, under *Sampling*, I set *Render* to *No Anti-Aliasing*.

This displays the following commands in the info window:

```py
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'BLENDER_WORKBENCH'
bpy.context.scene.render_aa = 'OFF'
```

When I try the same commands in the console, or in a stand-alone script, I get the following error:

```py
AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'render_aa'
```

Why is the info window lying to me?

Further, how can I turn off anti-aliasing in the Workbench engine with python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The anti-aliasing for the Workbench engine can be turned off through:

```
bpy.context.scene.display.render_aa = 'OFF'
```

The API manual is very helpful for cases where the Python command is unclear. The `render_aa` property is part of the class [`bpy.types.SceneDisplay`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SceneDisplay.html#bpy.types.SceneDisplay). Searching for this type shows that [`bpy.context.scene`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.display) contains a reference to an object of that type.

The reason why the command is displayed incorrectly seems related to [T69803](https://developer.blender.org/T69803). The Python tooltips are incomplete for `PropertyGroups` because `RNA_path_full_property_py_ex()`(`rna_access.c`) doesn't return a full path. This is also the reason why you see Python tooltips with missing parts like `bpy.data.scenes["Scene"] ... render_aa` for the *Render* anti-aliasing property in the UI.

**TL;DR** It's a bug.